# Can someone explain the behaviour of named vectors in manual ggplot scales?

Tags: r, ggplot2, nse

When using a named vector to set colours in a manual scale in ggplot2, if you use a variable as one of the names, the colour will not appear in the final plot.

```
library(ggplot2)

first_species <- 'setosa'
colours <- c(first_species = 'black',
             'versicolor'  = 'cadetblue',
             'virginica'   = 'hotpink')

ggplot(iris) +
  aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, colour = Species) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = colours)
```

[image: Missing a colour]

However, if I create the named vector using names, the plot appears as expected:

```
colours <- c('black', 'cadetblue', 'hotpink')
names(colours) <- c(first_species, 'versicolor', 'virginica')

ggplot(iris) +
  aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, colour = Species) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = colours)
```

[image: Correct plot]

Can anyone explain this behaviour to me? I suspect it is related to non-standard evaluation (ggplot2 is using the name rather than the value?).

Suggestions the best way to use a variable in the manual scale setting functions, would be appreciated!

Comment: in the first example, after colours <- c(first_species = 'black',  versicolor'  = 'cadetblue',  'virginica'   = 'hotpink') , if you check the names(colours) , you will find that first name is set to "first_species" instead of "setosa".                      

This is the reason why while plotting ggplot() is unable to find "first_species" in the data and so doesn't plot.

Comment: If you want a single line of code for setting names instead of using two lines with `names` you can use `setNames`, which is a convenience function for that situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do something like:

```
c(n=1)
```

Its like doing:

```
runif(n=10)
```

The `n` is a name here, and isn't evaluated like it was a variable. Its a named argument. That you can quote names like `runif("n"=10)` is a feature of the parser that lets you put otherwise unparsable names as arguments:

```
list("this has spaces" = 99) # works, list(this has spaces=99) fails
```

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. To confirm: the names in a named vector are something different from just characters?

Comment: I think part of my confusion is that `is.character(names(colours))` is true. But I assume the names function converts to character.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that you can do this: `c(is = 4, a = 5, thing = 8)`. I guess I thought that `c()` worked differently from other functions that take named arguments. Okay this makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, if you look at the named vector `colours` you created, you will see that it didn't evaluate `first_species`, it simply assigned it as the name.

```
first_species <- 'setosa'
colours <- c(first_species = 'black',
             'versicolor'  = 'cadetblue',
             'virginica'   = 'hotpink')

colours
# first_species    versicolor     virginica 
#       "black"   "cadetblue"     "hotpink"
```

You can get R to evaluate that variable by calling it using `setNames`:

```
colours <- setNames(c("black", "cadetblue", "hotpink" ), 
                    c(first_species, "versicolor", "virginica"))

colours
#      setosa  versicolor   virginica 
#     "black" "cadetblue"   "hotpink"
```

Now you get the desired plot:

```
ggplot(iris) +
  aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, colour = Species) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = colours)
```

[image: plot output]