# How to specify aesthetics by group in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to compare distributions using `geom_density`, but I want one of the distributions to have no fill. I can describe more easily using the following example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
iris %>% ggplot() + 
   geom_density(aes(x = Sepal.Width, color = Species, fill = Species), alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

How can I make it so that the virginica species is illustrated with a solid black line and no fill?

Comment: You can manually specify values to `scale_*_manual()`

Comment: For example see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65451154/13210554). Using a named vector of colors ensures the right color always goes with the right group.

Comment: How would you specify the empty fill? It appears that NA in scale_color_manual will plug in the default color.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Could try `alpha('black', 0)`. Bit of a hack though

Comment: Use "NA" in quotes _e.g._ `+ scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "NA"))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_density(aes(fill = Species), alpha = 0.5) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("setosa" = "red", 
                               "versicolor" = "green", 
                               "virginica" = "NA"))
```

Result:

[image]